# Gradle, Java conflicts between a file jar dependency and maven central dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gradle, dependency-management

I am trying to add a dependency as jar file and that jar is shipped with all the classes which are needed for it to run.

```
compile files('lib/org.hl7.fhir.igpublisher.jar')
```

Along with that, I have few other dependencies which are added as maven dependencies.

```
compile ("ca.uhn.hapi.fhir:hapi-fhir-base:2.3")
```

Now I am facing a lot of issues related to class conflicts because same classes have been shipped with different versions.

In an ideal case, how should I solve this problem? I want to say that the local jar should always use its own files and other dependencies should ignore the local jar files.

**Note:-** I am using IntelliJ idea.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky problem. There is only one classpath and multiple versions of the same class mean that only one of that versions is visible and the other ones are hidden.

One should generally avoid to declare dependencies on "fat jars" that contain their own dependencies. If possible, one should use the slim version without the dependencies (often both versions are published). If there is not alternative one can construct such a slim jar yourself by manually splitting up the jar file. It is also possible to control the structure by carefully ordering the dependencies on the classpath, but this is a little brittle.